# Should I update to Swift 3 to use Charts library version 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I am using Swift 2.2. But as per requirement of [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), I need to upgrade **Charts** to version 3. Should I migrate to Swift version 3 or I can use this library of version 3 in my Swift 2.2.

Comment: You should migrate to Swift 3. You. Anna mix Swift 2.2 and swift 3 n the same project

Comment: Swift 4 is out. Swift 2 is dead. You should migrate to Swift 3 for many reasons.

Comment: i am not taking about mixing about both swift version. Can i use danielgindi/Charts of version 3 in my swift 2.2?

Comment: Charts v3 is written in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charts v3 is strictly compatible for Swift 3+. ([Charts v2 is for Swift 2.3](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/legacy/v2))

And no, you can't mix Swift 2.x and Swift 3.x in the same project. So yes, you should migrate to **Swift 3.1** (latest stable).

Note: in the future (Xcode 9), you'll be able to mix Swift 3.2 with Swift 4.0, so it will be easier to transition for this kind of situations.

Comment: i am not taking about mixing about both swift version. Can i use danielgindi/Charts of version 3 in my swift 2.2?

Comment: @jennysam No, you can't use Charts version 3 in a Swift 2 project.